# using template classes as method parameters

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing

I've two template classes: Class1< S > and Class2< T >. In Class2< T >, there's a method that has as parameter a pointer to an object of Class1< S >. Should I then re-define class2< T > to class2< S, T >? or is there any other best solution?
The problem, is that I might have new methods referring to objects of other template classes as parameters. Therefore, I would to avoid having sth. like: class2< S, T , U ...>

```
template < class S >
class Class1{
    public:
        ...
    private:
        ...
};

template < class T >
class Class2{
    public:
        ...
        Class2<T> * doSomething(Class1<S> * );
        ...
    private:
        ...
};

template < class S, class T >
class Class2{
    public:
        ...
        Class2<T> * doSomething(Class1<S> * );
        ...
    private:
        ...
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of object that `Class2::doSomething` acts upon should not have to be part of `Class2`'s type.  So make `Class2::doSomething()` a [Member Function Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swta9c6e.aspx):

```
template < class T >
class Class2{
    public:
        ...
        template<class S> Class2<T> * doSomething(Class1<S> * );
        ...
    private:
        ...
};
```

**EDIT:**

Defining the member function template is easy enough if you do it inline, but sometimes you can't or don't want to do that, and then some funky syntax comes in to play.  Here's a complete example that illustrates both how to define the member function template, and how to call it.  I've changed the names to be a little easier to read & follow.

```
template<class FooType> class Foo
{
};

template<class BarType> class Bar
{
public:
    template<class FooType> Bar<BarType>* doSomething(Foo<FooType>* foo);
};

template<typename BarType> template<typename FooType> Bar<BarType>* Bar<BarType>::doSomething(Foo<FooType>* foo)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Foo<unsigned> foo_1;
    Bar<double> bar_1;
    Bar<double> * bar_copy = 0;
    bar_copy = bar_1.doSomething<unsigned>(&foo_1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And when I initialize/use the objects, it would be sth. like: Class1<int> objClass1; Class2<float> objC2_1, *objC2_2;  objC2_2 = objC2_1.doSomething(&objClass1); right?

Comment: +1, nice explanation of the tricky out-of-line syntax.  I think the `<unsigned>` in `bar_1.doSomething<unsigned>(&foo_1);` is not necessary though -- won't it be inferred?

Comment: @j:  probably true.  i cant check at this moment tho, and I usually just type the template params explicitly

Comment: @John,the definition/implementation of the template class is separated (.h & .cpp files) & also I include an .inc file @the end of the .cpp file to initialize the template classes,e.g,(bar-impl.inc) template class Bar<float>;template class Bar<int>; same for foo-impl.inc: template class Foo<int>;template class Foo<float>;(www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13).Now,I get the msg: /tmp/ccBySVYZ.o: In function `main':
bar.cpp:(.text+0x19f):undefined reference to `void Bar<float>::doSomething<float>(Foo<float>*)'
collect2:ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [imagetest] Error 1

Comment: @Javier:  You can't put template definitions in a CPP file, at least not without some acrobatics.  You can put the definition in an HPP file, and then `#include` that HPP file directly from your header file. Here's one link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185954/implications-of-template-declaration-definition/2186021#2186021

Comment: @John,thanks for the link.However,I would like to use "Explicit Instantiation" of templates.Up to now, I was able to declare the template class in a .h file, its implementation in a .cpp file, and the explicit instantiation of the template class in a .inc file (template class Bar<float>; ...). I would like to follow the same protocol, so my doubt is basically which will be the template instantiation for the doSomething method? BTW, you used "typename" instead of "class", template<typename BarType> template<typename FooType>... why it couldn't be template<class BarType> template<class FooType>?

Comment: You can do explicit instantiation.  I answered a question some time back that explains exactly how to do this, but I can't find it just now.  Will continue to look.

Comment: @John, What if I have a method in class Bar that returns a pointer for class Foo: template<class FooType> Foo<FooType>* doSomething1(int); I was having some problems in this case: "error: no matching function for call to "Bar<float>::doSomething1(int&)"